# Extract directory names from given path and match it

Tags: bash

What would be the best way to extract all the directory names from a path and compare it with directory name given as argument:

```
find_dir() {
path='/download/1/2/3/4/5/6'
for dir in logic ${path}
  if [ dir = $1 ]; then
      echo "Directory $1 found in $path"
      exit(0)
  else
      pass
  fi
echo "Directory $1 not found in $path"
}
```

**Results:**

```
pompt$ find_dir 4
Directory 4 found in /download/1/2/3/4/5/6

pompt$ find_dir 8
Directory 8 not found in /download/1/2/3/4/5/6
```

Comment: Your account is confusing as it is peculiarly very similar to [@devnull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235132/devnull)'s account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use regex match wrapping directory name within `/` (note the `if [[ $dir =~ .*/$1/.* ]] ; then` syntax, double brackets, space before semi-colon and `=~` for regex test):

```
#!/bin/bash
find_dir() {
path='/download/1/2/3/4/5/6'
for dir in logic ${path}
 do
  if [[ "$dir" =~ .*/$1/.* ]] ; then
      echo "Directory $1 found in $path"
      exit 0
  fi
 done
echo "Directory $1 not found in $path"
}

find_dir 8
find_dir 4
```

result:

```
Directory 8 not found in /download/1/2/3/4/5/6
Directory 4 found in /download/1/2/3/4/5/6
```

note: I preserved the `for` loop but the `logic` argument doesn't make any sense...

Comment: The way i read the post, it seems `for dir in logic $path` is meant to ask `put whatever logic is appropriate here`.

Comment: Thanks for the instant response. `regex` make sense. Let me try this. BTW the `logic` in `for` loop was just a dummy.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

find_dir() {
    path='/download/1/2/3/4/5/6'
    lastdir=$(rev <<< "$path" | cut -f1 -d/)
    n=1
    while [[ $dir != $lastdir ]]; do
        dir=$(cut -f$n -d/ <<< "$path")
        ((n++))
        if [[ $dir == $1 ]]; then
           echo "Directory $1 found in $path"
           exit 0
        fi
    done
    echo "Directory $1 not found in $path"
}
```